# jquery smooth scrolling gone wrong in opera

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, opera, scrolltop

I just tried a snippet of code on the latest version of opera and it won't do the animation! it just goes straight up (I'm trying to anchor back to top with a smooth animation)

how can I solve this?

code:

```
$(function(){
  $(".top").click(function(document){
    $("html, body").animate({scrollTop:0},"slow");
  });
})
```

EDIT: I'm on Opera 11.01 build 1190.

Comment: Hmm, tested on Opera 11.10 Beta and it works well: http://jsfiddle.net/jhBw3/2/

Comment: hey blender! I'm on 11.01 build 1190 and it doesn't work, it goes straight up as if I only had some html anchor and then some delayed animation bit appears in the header.

Answer (score 1):

Solution is easy by this http://free-top.tym.cz/forum/javascript/index.php?ds=scroll-window-smoothly-javascript:

```
$(function(){
  $(".top").click(function(document){
    if( $.browser.opera) {
       $("html").animate({scrollTop:0},"slow");
     } else {
       $("html, body").animate({scrollTop:0},"slow");
     }
  });
})
```